# Version conflicts while using spring boot azure blob storage

Tags: spring-boot, maven, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload image to azure blob using spring boot application. I am getting below errors

> 2022-02-02 23:28:39 [qtp1371397528-21] INFO  16824 c.a.c.i.jackson.JacksonVersion - info:Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.12.4, jackson-core=2.12.4, jackson-databind=2.12.4, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.12.4, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.12.4, azure-core=1.21.0

> 2022-02-02 23:28:39 [qtp1371397528-21] WARN  16824 org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - handleException:/api/v1/project/options/image/upload

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/logging/ByteBufFormat

Java code

```java
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString("connectionstring")
                .containerName("container-name")
                .buildClient();

        BlobClient client = containerClient.getBlobClient(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            client.upload(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("error is {}", e.getMessage());
        }
```

pom.xml

```xml
    <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>sample</name>

    <properties>
        <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <jackson-bom.version>2.12.4</jackson-bom.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--        Azure Blob-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Swagger/OpenAPI UI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Jersey-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.shiver-me-timbers</groupId>
            <artifactId>smt-random</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the very same problem with azure dependencies last few days.  Upgrading `spring-boot-starter-parent` to version `2.5.5` fixed it for me.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
</parent>
```